# Hot to get all indexed field names EmbeddedSolrServer?

Tags: solrj

I would like to get all the  dynamic field names in an index file. Is there a way to do it using solr java api?

Thanks,
Rathi

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found using solrj api, `searcher.getReader().getFieldNames()` will return all the indexed fields.